# ¿Como puedo Graficar utilizando MPAndroidChart las canciones de mi dispositivo móvil?

Tags: java, android, content-provider

Lo que planeo es graficar las canciones de mi dispositivo es una grafica de tipo barras con relación ID de la canción y duracion de la misma.

```
 ArrayList<BarEntry> BARENTRY ;
ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels ;

private ArrayList<GraficaSong> songList;
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_estadisticas, container,false);

    BarChart chart1 = (BarChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bar_chart1);
    BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();
    songList = new ArrayList<>();

    BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

    AddValuesToBARENTRY();

    //AddValuesToBarEntryLabels();
    Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");
    BARDATA = new BarData( Bardataset);
    Bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    chart1.setData(BARDATA);
    chart1.animateY(3000);
    return rootView;
}
```

**El metodo**

de agregar fue así donde doy realizo un cursor y dendro de un ciclo while obtenga los valores de las columnas que están marcadas en el código.

```
public void AddValuesToBARENTRY() {

    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, mediaProjection, null, null, null);
    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //AGREGAR CANCIONES A LA LISTA EN UN CICLO
        do {

            BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID), 
                    musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)));

        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());

    }
}
```

Comment: que problema tienes?

Comment: Basicamente lo que quiero es graficar las canciones de mi dispositivo en relacion duracion y cancion y que no muestre las todas si no las 15 con mayor duracion

Comment: ¿Con esto que has hecho te muestra el gráfico con todas las canciones que tienes? Si es así, ya tienes hecho lo más difícil. Ahora te tocaría analizar las canciones tú mismo y establecer los criterios que quieras para incluirlas en el gráfico o no. No hay una manera de hacerlo automática. Tienes que ordenar las canciones tú y decidir cuales incluyes o no.